# Fetch Api Data SwiftUI

Tags: api, swiftui

I need to add `author_id` to the api so that it can give me all the articles of the author.

Here in `SelectedAuthorView`, I fetch related `authorPost`. In this `authorPost` it has `author_id` as well.

Below is my `SelectedAuthorView`, here I tried to fetch api data but first I do not want to fetch api inside the view. Second I do not know how to transfer this selected authorPost to my `AuthorService`

```
struct SelectedAuthorView: View {
var authorPost: AuthorPost
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                AuthorListElementView(authorPost: authorPost)
                if let selectedAuthorUrl = URL(string:"http://xxxx\(authorPost.author_id)/") {
                    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                    var request = URLRequest(url: selectedAuthorUrl)
                    request.httpMethod = "GET"
                    do {
                        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: Any, options: .prettyPrinted)
                    } catch let error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                } 
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Also this is the api I need to fetch data from [![enter image description here][1]][1]

Help is needed to be able to fetch data from that api.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ViewModel` : `ObservableObject`

And your code will be like that :

`The viewModel` :

```
    class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
      
      func fetchData(authorPost: AuthorPost){
      if let selectedAuthorUrl = URL(string:"http://yazar.io/api/author/article/list/\(authorPost.author_id)/") {
                    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                    var request = URLRequest(url: selectedAuthorUrl)
                    request.httpMethod = "GET"
                    do {
                        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: Any, options: .prettyPrinted)
                    } catch let error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                } 
      }
    }
```

.

```
struct SelectedAuthorView: View {
var authorPost: AuthorPost 
@ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                AuthorListElementView(authorPost: authorPost)
             }
         }.onAppear{
           self.viewModel.fetchData(authorPost:authorPost)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to // -- > here your need to put the fetched data in authorPost

Comment: @MertKöksal I updated my response , now it should work for you

Comment: Thanks, but there I am having an error inside selectedAuthorView.